# Bootstrap navigation bar affix property not accurate after window resize

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, window-resize

I'm having a problem which involves the affix property in Bootstrap. Using the jQuery below it functions completely fine as far as sticking to the top of the page after scrolling down (as intended). **The problem only occurs after the page has loaded and then the window is resized VERTICALLY.** At this point the navigation bar no longer "sticks" to the top at the correct point while scrolling. SEE DEMO SITE [HERE](http://amdiamonddesigns.000space.com/).

Essentially the problem seems to be that the height at which the navigation bar becomes affixed is assigned after window load, and if the page is vertically resized after that then the height at which it should begin "sticking" to the top of the page SHOULD change, but doesn't. Nothing too complicated in the JS here:

```
//"sticky" nav bar
    $('#navbar').affix({
        offset: {
            top: $(window).height()
        }
    });
    $('#navbar').on('affix.bs.affix', function () {
        var navHeight = $('#navbar').outerHeight(true);
        $('#body').css('margin-top', navHeight);
    });
    $('#navbar').on('affix-top.bs.affix', function () {
        $('#body').css('margin-top', 0);
    });
```

I basically just need a way to have the point at which it "sticks" change after resize but I can't seem to get `$(window).resize` working effectively with it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to accomplish?  http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/2t5WB/  This is just using the built in behaviors of Bootstrap scrollspy and no extra JS.  Here's an alternate approach that uses scrolltop: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/eY8nQ/  Sorry, maybe it's a bit too early for me, but I'm not following your logic above.

Comment: I edited to hopefully clarify. The "sticking" effect you're demonstrating works fine (the nav bar is below the home splash so that may be a bit confusing), the issue is only after resize.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to accomplish is having the offset of your navbar updated dynamically on window.resize.  If that is true than this will accomplish that.

You have the ability to update any of the properties of the affix plugin after it is intialized.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#navbar').data('bs.affix').options.offset = $('#navbar').offset().top;
});
```